# JavaScript ignore missing DOM element/event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a new application where different pages has different DOM element like `Map page` has some map specific element and `Message page` has message specific. To reduce the number of requests, I am combining all scripts to one file and put into footer.

But the problem is that when I am on `Map Page`, getting error for the missing elements that are only exists on `Message page`, I believe I am missing something very easy but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Don't add the scripts ment to message-page to map-page, bundling every script to a single file is not always the best solution.

Comment: Then you must be using jQuery incorrectly (or loading it in your page but not actually using it). Unmatched selectors never trigger errors.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can use try and catch if you don't want your script stops.</strike>

i.e.

```
try{
var test = document.getElementById("someelementthatdontexsist");
alert(test.innerHTML);
}
catch(err){};
```

so as Esko suggested you need to use "if" to check if you are on right page to run appropriate code.

sample:

```js
    var PageName = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

    document.getElementById("check_button").addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (PageName[0].getAttribute('id') == "map_page") {
            //do map_page things
            document.getElementById("page_name").innerText = PageName[0].getAttribute('id');
        }
        if (PageName[0].getAttribute('id') == "message_page") {
            //do message_page things
            document.getElementById("page_name").innerText = PageName[0].getAttribute('id');
        }
    });
```

```html
<body id="map_page">
    <button id="check_button">Check page</button>
    <span id="page_name">test
</span>
</body>
```

Comment: This is very bad practice and an [anti pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why) that should not be used. Just add one if-statement to check if the element was found.

Comment: @Esko thanks a lot for your comment, i didn't knew about it. But way the author of question is loading scripts shows that he don't need best practices at this case. If the script file will have hundreds of elements to check, checking every element can take a while. What do you think?

Comment: No you don't have to create hundreds of ifs to do this. You only need one if to check if you are on the right page (find the parent element or one of the elements that are only on that page). Also, you should always try to use good practices and more importantly when suggesting a solution ***not*** to teach others to use bad practises in the first place.

Comment: @Esko thanks again for your instructions, i am new here but i will remember your lesson.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I'm sure your intentions are sincere :) You can also modify your answer according to what we discussed, create an example where you check if your test variable hold a dom-element or not and offer that as a solution and I will upvote your answer.